# Application closes when rotate Gmaps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services

I have an application with Gmaps in it, it's works fine when it's in portrait mode, but closes when I rotate to landscape mode, it doesn't crash, but just closes!

In the LogCat i get this,

```
09-19 16:24:24.056: W/ResourceType(20122): getEntry failing because entryIndex 939 is beyond type entryCount 1
09-19 16:24:24.056: W/ResourceType(20122): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b03ab (t=10 e=939) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
09-19 16:24:24.056: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(20122): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

But the google play services is there, and it's up to date.

Anyone have any clue? Thanks

Comment: Possibly related to the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr

Comment: it's not the same error! my app shows, everything is working, until i try to rotate and it close, it's doesn't eve crash!

Comment: Based on what you've posted, it's the same error with different numbers. Can you share any more of the Logcat output? You mentioned that the app "doesn't crash", but is a stacktrace generated?

Comment: that's all on the LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the screen orientation changes in your manifest for you activity like this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change: