# Android Google Admob: Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to use the Google Mobile Adds SDK.

I have followed the guide here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play but have some errors when running my program.

The adverts appear to be working, but I get the following error (seems to occur 3 times every time an advert is loaded):

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I have imported the google_play_services-lib and haven't been able to resolve this issue.

If I run the adverts without using test device I also get the warning appearing many times:

```
PicturePileLayerContent: Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

Comment: I am seeing the same results after updating to the new Google Play Services ads, not sure what the issue is but everything seems to work.

Comment: GooglePlayServicesUtil resources messages is a benign error log. Hopefully the false positive logging of it will get fixed in a future version.

Comment: I think this can be a solution.
In my case, it works.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933664/2419613

Answer (score 2):

Check this from : **https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound**

> **I keep getting the error 'The Google Play services resources were not found.**
>
> **Check your project configuration to ensure that the
> resources are included.' You can safely ignore this message. Your app
> will still fetch and serve banner ads.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the google-play-services-lib as a library-project. They updated the sdk. There are several tutorials around. For Eclipse it is easy:

Right click project -> properties -> Android

Add the liberary project google play service lib.

For more detailed walkthroughs

[importing the library-project](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435/)!

[how to get GoogleMaps running on emulator](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/blog/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator//)!