# the google play services resources were not found error using admob

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to get interestial ads from admob, but there is an error related to play services resources.

Here is my error log cat.

The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

12-19 00:08:48.240: W/ResourceType(10113): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 5 
Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely to do with how LocationServices is configured on your device.

See [LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)

Answer (score 1):

Does your ad show?

From Googles Mobile Ads page:

> I keep getting the error 'The Google Play services resources were not
>   found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources
>   are included.' You can safely ignore this message. Your app will still
>   fetch and serve banner ads.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/

I get this "*error*" as well but my ads are served and I can just ignore it until they patch it up.