# Getting on AdMobs problems

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm having some strange problems with starting with AdMobs.

**FIRST PROBLEM**

When I try to add my banner by this code:

```
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.adprincipal);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("my unit id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()  
    .addTestDevice("my device")  
    .build();
    // Load the adView with the ad request.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    layout.addView(adView);
```

I don't get anything if I set the size `AdSize.SMART_BANNER` but I get a test banner with `AdSize.BANNER` but ANYWAY (even BANNER and SMART_BANNER) this is what I get from LogCat:

*WHEN BANNER*

> 12-30 04:41:00.380: W/ResourceType(27407): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 5
>
> 12-30 04:41:00.380: W/ResourceType(27407): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>
> 12-30 04:41:00.380: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27407): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>
> 12-30 04:41:00.400: W/ResourceType(27407): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 5
>
> 12-30 04:41:00.400: W/ResourceType(27407): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>
> 12-30 04:41:00.400: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27407): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>
> 12-30 04:41:02.111: I/GATE(27407): DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED
>
> 12-30 04:41:02.111: I/Ads(27407): Ad finished loading.

*WHEN SMART_BANNER*

> 12-30 04:48:27.476: W/ResourceType(29507): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 5
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.476: W/ResourceType(29507): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.476: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29507): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.516: D/OpenGLRenderer(29507): Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.576: W/ResourceType(29507): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 5
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.576: W/ResourceType(29507): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>
> 12-30 04:48:27.576: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(29507): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: I/Ads(29507): No fill from ad server.
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: W/Ads(29507): Failed to load ad: 3
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: E/SQLiteLog(29507): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: E/SQLiteLog(29507): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) -
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: D/WebKit(29507): ERROR:
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: D/WebKit(29507): SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: D/WebKit(29507): Cause - unable to open database file
>
> 12-30 04:48:31.450: D/WebKit(29507): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)

and the SMART BANNER doesn't load

**SECOND PROBLEM**

I got the same errors than "BANNER" setting an INTERSTITIAL, but it also finally loads...

What's wrong??

I've tried: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956048/should-we-prefer-admob-in-google-play-services-compared-to-old-admob-sdk), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665988/the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-error-using-admob) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)
I have reinstalled my library, downloaded the lastet, deleted and reinstalled... etcetera.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you running this application on device or emulator?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Always on device.

Comment: Do check whether you have installed any ad blocker or not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On emulator change following:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()  
    .addTestDevice("my device")  
    .build();
```

to

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
        .addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB")  // Emulator id you will get in the LogCat verbose
        .build();
       adView.loadAd(request);
```

On real device:

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Also, check on your Ad server (most problably AdMob), if the Ad for your ad_unit_id has BANNER, SMART BANNER and INTERSTITIAL enabled.

Comment: Now suddenly it works also for SMART_BANNER but the errors are coming on anyway.

I checked on AdMobs and it's counting impressions as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. The BANNER settings where wrong on AdMob site

Comment: Tasty I'm facing same issue, sometime SMART_BANNER isn't loading in landscape mode, I implemented recommended answer but issue isn't resolved to me. furthermore I cant find any setting for SMART_BANNER on AdMob site, could you highlight which setting you followed?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this message. This is written in the Google Mobile Ads SDK FAQ.

See this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound)