# Google Admob for Android Issue: Google Play Services were not found

Tags: android, admob

This thread may seems duplicate(and the solution is to import Google Play library). However, I can assure that I have correctly imported since my Google Map API is working as it should, and added necessary manifest items. Using the code sample from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals ,I'm getting the error as titled and seeing a black layout.

Any idea?

LogCat below is generated using Google-provided working code, then imported with my G.Play Libraries...

```
 01-31 13:30:45.869: I/Ads(11130): Starting ad request.
01-31 13:30:45.877: I/dalvikvm(11130): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture, referenced from method abz.<init>
01-31 13:30:45.881: W/dalvikvm(11130): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3345: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (Z)V
01-31 13:30:45.881: D/dalvikvm(11130): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003d
01-31 13:30:46.001: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11130): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-31 13:30:46.049: D/libEGL(11130): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-31 13:30:46.061: D/(11130): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb932cbb8, tid 11130
01-31 13:30:46.077: D/libEGL(11130): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-31 13:30:46.077: D/libEGL(11130): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-31 13:30:46.193: W/EGL_emulation(11130): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-31 13:30:46.217: D/OpenGLRenderer(11130): Enabling debug mode 0
01-31 13:30:46.285: D/OpenGLRenderer(11130): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb92860f0): name, size, mSize = 1, 1048576, 1048576
01-31 13:30:46.301: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11130): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-31 13:30:46.305: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11130): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-31 13:30:46.437: D/OpenGLRenderer(11130): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb92a4580): name, size, mSize = 2, 9216, 1057792
01-31 13:30:46.545: D/OpenGLRenderer(11130): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb926c1f0): name, size, mSize = 4, 36864, 1094656
01-31 13:30:47.525: I/Ads(11130): Ad finished loading.
```

Comment: can you post the package name of a google maps class? such as `com.google.android.*.*.*`

Comment: import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

Comment: p/s: Google provided example project is having the same issue too...

Comment: Where is the error appearing? If it's in logcat, can you copy/paste relevant sections here.

Comment: This is weird. The finally loads and appearing itself now; but the error of libraries not found is still there

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr/23044931#23044931).
Note that if you're getting ads served, then you can ignore these errors as [noted in this faq](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a bug in the Google Play Services SDK. Check out [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=704#c17). It should work fine but there will be an incorrect error in the log.