# Two questions about google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I made an app that shows Google map.

- First question:

  Everything works fine in my app, but I see this error in logCat part every time that I run the app on my tablet,

  `E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(566): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.`

  Why does it give me this error?
- Second question:

  I want to understand why it must connect to internet for loading Google map page? if I want it work offline, what do I do ? and how can I make app that shows Google map page in offline way?

Answer (score 0):

1. [LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)
2. Yes at first it must connect but then there are options like make available offline to use it offline, so you will need to cache it or something like that

Comment: 1.you mean ,the google play service that installed in every android device?(it installed by company already).2.I know it can uses cach memory that it pushed already in my tablet's memory,but if I want that it show me new place that it hadn't loaded in cache , it doesn't work anymore and it doesn't show google map page anymore,and I must connect to internet for it.

Comment: @user3237265 1. See the updated answer 2. So show new places you must have had connection to internet or have saved it earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your atention, and your answering...I read thhat linke about a week ago but I didn't get anythings that has realated to my question?but I want to read it again...

Comment: That link should answer all your doubts. Do you mind putting a tick by my question if you are satisfied?

Comment: I read it again but when I add this method "setMyLocationEnabled(true);" I get this error :"The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.".I don't know how can I solve it?:(

Comment: which android device version you tested? @user3237265

Comment: Android version is 4.2.2

Comment: I think , I got it... there are two files in this direction "sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs" and google-play-services.jar is 937kb but google-play-services.jar.properties is 1kb. May it is the resone?!

Comment: @user3237265 It Might be!