# Android Admob implementation: Get the error : "Google Play Services resources were not found"

Tags: android, admob

I tried to upgrade my implementation of AdMob. Using the GoogleAdMobSDK, I would like to turn into the google-play-services-lib.

The ad appears. So it seems ok, but I still got this error at the method call loadAd() in log

```
    Requesting resource 0x7f0c000d failed because it is complex
    GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Here's my checklist:

- I import the library project in my workspace, copying the source.
- I reference the library into my project
- I add the meta-data in the Manifest

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```
- My code

  ```
  this.request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(id).build();
  this.adView = new AdView(context);
  this.adView.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
  this.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
  ...
  this.adView.loadAd(request);
  ```

The target version for my app in 9 (2.3). I test on Nexus 5 with KitKat version.

I also tried to put the google-play-services-lib jar in the properties, but no result.

I want to be sure that this error could be handle before submit my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr

Comment: Is the google-play-services_lib.jar listed under "android dependencies" when you click the arrow, and is it selected for Export?  Have latest version 4.2 (Rev 15)?

Comment: Yes for everything. As William said, it seems to be a benign error. But I'll keep a watch out for next update of the library

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr/23044931#23044931).
Note that if you're getting ads served, then you can ignore these errors as [noted in this faq](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a benign error with the current version of Google Play Services.
Don't worry about it. Submit your app. Get some sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And you're right : when I read again my post, I understood the meaning of your advice. But, in my defense, I'm French and this was my first technical post in English on stackoverflow. I'll do my best next time ;-)