# Admob not working at all:The Google Play services resources were not found.Check your project configuration

Tags: android, admob

[image: Project Settings]
I have tried everything, applied every solution I found. Checked googleplayservices many times. Still admob is not working.[here I see no need to worry.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152834/android-admob-implentation-get-the-error-google-play-services-resources-wer)

Does that mean if I submit my app, admob will work fine after submitting? If not here is my code for admob,how do I fix this?

```
private AdView adView;
adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("My App Ad Unit ID");

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adViewLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
       //     .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
         //   .addTestDevice("52EEC3DAD2FA75F22B44407D19072632")
            .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log pls

Comment: posted along project settings

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound) is what the google guys say over it

**I keep getting the error *'The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.'***

*You can safely ignore this message. Your app will still fetch and serve banner ads.*

Also this has bee asked several times so just ignore it