# Why does IntelliJ IDEA 13 require both lib project and lib itself (google-play-service) to be added as a dependency?

Tags: intellij-idea, google-play-services

Reading [Google instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), I found that I have to import and reference the Play Service library into the project.

So I created a project, copied `google-play-service_lib` project, imported it as a `library` project, went to the main project and added this library as a `Module dependency`. However, I still have an error that IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize package `com.amazon.device.ads.*`.

So I had to add a `library dependency` as well, although **this library already exists** in the `/lib` directory of Play Service library project.

Am I doing something wrong or we're actually requested to add both dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA? If yes, is this maybe a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 13? I can't remember of having to do the same in earlier versions of IntelliJ IDEA (I have been using it for three years).

This is how it looks in the end and it works only this way! Check the last two dependencies.

[image: (]

Comment: Can you detail the operations you did to include the google-play-services that way?

Comment: Remove the play-services_lib

Comment: @EngineerDollery Don't do that. The `play-services_lib` is needed for the `Manifest` file.