# "The Google Play services resources were not found....." error

Tags: android, google-play-services

When I try to run the Game with GooplayService, Logcat show the following error:

```
"The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to   
 ensure that the resources are included."
```

My code login Google Play Game Service:

```
@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

### Problem

when I tried to run the Game 2nd, its auto login Google play game service. I didn't get any error on the Device, but Logcat show the following error.

> "Unknown issue with google play service".

I can't login Google Play Game Service, and device show the above error.

I using Genymotion, lastest version of google play game service.

Comment: check this link please : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr

Comment: Check that whether have you installed Google Play Service App in your mobile? else kindly install from forllowing link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: @Sivakumar I installed GLSA in my device.

Comment: @AndreyMarkov
I searched it, but i keep getting error :(

ps: thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

It may be happen if GooglePlay library is not included in your project...

sometimes if your googleplay library is not in your worksplace (not copies in workspace) project do not get the refrence of that..

So, make sure your project and library is in same workspace.

Comment: I make sure my project and library is in same workspace.
But not able to fix :(