# Google play services resource not found

Tags: android

I am trying to put AdsMob on my application
 as per https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

But I am getting the Google play services resource not found in log cat
I've configured the play services lib project.

I've used the following code to check play services available in device which is successful
`int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
      Log.d("Success","device has play service");
}`

Please check the screenshots[image: Screenshot for the lib project setup]

[image: screenshot for errorlog]

Comment: possible duplicate of [LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem you should be worried about.

Google answers this in their [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#resourcesnotfound) and states, "You can safely ignore this message. Your app will still fetch and serve banner ads"