# The Google Play services resources were not found: what do I do now?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I know this problem is kind of common, but i literally tried everything to solve this error and i didn't come up with a solution. The problem with my app is that it doesn't log in in g+ (google play games), it shows the log-in screen, then the spinning circle and then it disappears without logging in, while on the *logcat* the only error that appears is this:

**`The Google Play services resources were not found. check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included`**

the problem with this is that i cannot access the google play leaderboards, but the ads load just fine!

I tried by placing *`google-play-services`*_lib and *`BaseGameUtils`* in the folder where all the projects are, and importing them from there but nothing.
I tried by placing *google-play-services*_lib and *BaseGameUtils* in the libs folder of the project, and importing them from there but nothing.

I made all the correct references, i did everything correct. I even tried different versions of *google-play-services*_lib and *BaseGameUtils* that i found on the internet, but nothing.

The funny thing is that the first times that i used the app everything was working fine, even though i had the error `**Google Play services resources were not found**`. I could access the leaderboards with no problems. But then after a day of testing (BTW during this period i didn't change anything on the project), the app just won't log in for some strange reason.

so maybe it's not even this error's fault, i have no idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)

Answer (score 0):

That error message is often  a red herring and can be ignored. e.g. my released app spits out that message every time it runs, and it logs in fine.

It can take a long time to  log in on an emulator the first time your app runs on it. Often I quit out and retry a couple of times. Look out for any other messages and the first thing to check if you are still having problems is the 12 character client id.