# Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi"

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm using Google Play Service v.9.2.1, (modules `ads-lite` and `basement`).
Admob test ads show fine, but some warnings are written to Logcat:

```
W/Ads(): Failed to instantiate ClientApi class.
W/Ads(): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi" on path: /data/app/myApp.apk
W/Ads():    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
W/Ads():    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
W/Ads():    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zzik(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zzil(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl$zza.zziu(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzl.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
W/Ads():    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
W/Ads(): ClientApi class cannot be loaded.
```

These warnings appear with no Proguard used. Do I need to include additional libraries?

Comment: Please share your (module-)gradle. And check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Since you're using mobile ads, you need to [add Proguard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/faq). This prevents all public methods on public classes in the Google Mobile Ads SDK from being obfuscated.

To safely use ProGuard with Google Mobile Ads, add the following to your ProGuard config:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
public *;
}
```

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/GZsXftJA3BE/qZZX2aCMCgAJ) may offer you additonal insight as well.