# Google Drive REST API Resumable upload returnin 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, rest, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to uploading chunks of 256 KB in Google Drive using REST API v3. I can successfully get the upload ID but when I use this upload ID to upload a chunk, I get a 400 Bad Request instead of 308. I am posting the code below. The method getUploadID() initiates a resumable upload session and the method putFileWithUploadID() should upload a chunk of the file but there seems to be a problem in it. I have written the code according to the official [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload).

```
String mUploadID;
private String getUploadID(Uri fileUri, String token) {
    String upload_id = "";
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
    String fileName = fileContent.getName();
    String mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
    try {
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Type", mimeType);
        con.setRequestProperty("X-Upload-Content-Length", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", fileContent.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        String body = "{\"name\": \"" + fileName + "\", \"parents\": [\"" + "0B7ypsm4HGZhCS3FXcldPZnFPNkE" + "\"]}";
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", body.getBytes().length));
        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(body.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        con.connect();
        String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        if (location.contains("upload_id")) {
            String[] uploadParameters = location.split("upload_id");
            upload_id = uploadParameters[1].replace("=", "");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return upload_id;
}

private void putFileWithUploadID(Uri fileUri, String token, long range) {
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
    String fileName = fileContent.getName();
    String contentLength = String.valueOf(fileContent.length());
    String mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
    long totalBytesFromDataInputStream = 0;
    long uploadedBytes = 0;
    long chunkStart = 0;
    long chunkSize = 262144;
    do {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=" + mUploadID;
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mimeType);
            uploadedBytes = chunkSize;
            if (chunkStart + uploadedBytes > fileContent.length()) {
                uploadedBytes = (int) fileContent.length() - chunkStart;
            }
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", uploadedBytes));
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", "bytes " + chunkStart + "-" + (chunkStart + uploadedBytes - 1) + "/" + fileContent.length());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) uploadedBytes];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileContent);
            fileInputStream.getChannel().position(chunkStart);
            if (fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, (int) uploadedBytes) == -1) {
                break;
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            outputStream.close();
            con.connect();
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            String rangeHeader = con.getHeaderField("Range");
            if (rangeHeader!=null) {
                chunkStart = Long.parseLong(rangeHeader.substring(rangeHeader.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, rangeHeader.length())) + 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while ((chunkStart+chunkSize)<fileContent.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [400: Bad Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) means that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

> This error can be thrown when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph.

You may also check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455422/android-resumable-upload-to-google-drive/24459799#24459799) which suggested to properly use the Android-specific API to do resumable upload. See [creating files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file).

Comment: I am not using Android-specific API because it does not provide a way to get upload progress and in my code above, I do not know what I am not providing or providing something invalid.